# Zf2 filter compress, saving the archive

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zip

I'm using this php code:

```
$filter = new \Zend\Filter\Compress(array(
    'adapter' => 'zip',
    'options' => array(
        'archive' => $chpt->getTitle().'.zip'
    ),
));
$compressed = $filter->filter($dir[0]);
```

it creates an archive and all works, but i want to save this archive in a specific directory. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid question. I'm writing this answer for everyone who need an help.

I changed the code:

```
    $filter = new \Zend\Filter\Compress(array(
        'adapter' => 'zip',
        'options' => array(
            'archive' => '/path/to/file.zip'
        ),
    ));
$compressed = $filter->filter('path/to/folder');
```

using `'archive' => '/path/to/file.zip'` you are saving the zip where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `target` into your filter options :

```
$filter = new \Zend\Filter\Compress(array(
    'adapter' => 'zip',
    'options' => array(
        'archive' => $chpt->getTitle().'.zip',
        'target' => $your_path // default is '.' 
    ),
));
```